# Cellular approximation to the diagonal of $\mathbb{R}P^2$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $\mathbb{R}P^2=e^0\cup e^1\cup e^2$ be the real projective plane given its standard CW structure. Give $\mathbb{R}P^2\times\mathbb{R}P^2$ the product CW structure.

> Does anyone know an explicit formula for a cellular approximation to the diagonal map $\Delta:\mathbb{R}P^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}P^2\times\mathbb{R}P^2$, $[x,y,z]\mapsto ([x,y,z],[x,y,z])$?

Comment: Can you just decompose it as a simplicial complex and take the realization of the diagonal map coming from viewing it as a simplicial set? I think this could be made completely explicit.

Answer (score 2):

I've just uploaded a file on this [Diagonals.pdf](//groupoids.org.uk/pdffiles/Diagonals.pdf). This gives diagonal approximations for the fundamental crossed complexes $\Pi X_*$ of the standard cell structures $X_*$ of the Torus, Klein Bottle and Projective Plane. The diagonal approximatiions are maps $d:C \to C \otimes C$ where $\otimes$ is the monoidal part of the monoidal closed structure on the category of crossed complexes. See the book referenced [BHS11] in the preprint.

To give the details for the Projective Plane $P$, with cell structure $e^0 \cup e^1 \cup e^2$, and with boundary of the $2$-cell $e$ given by $\delta e= 2a$, say. Thus a diagonal in dimension $1$ is given by $\Delta(a) = a_1 + a_2$.  In dimension $2$ it is given by 
 $$\Delta(e) = (-a_1 )\otimes (-a_2) +e_1 ^{-a_2} +e_2.$$
This is fairly explicit, but is not given in terms of coordinates.

Comment: That's kinda cool, but I'm afraid not quite what I was looking for. I was hoping for topological, rather than algebraic, information. i.e. an actual map.

Comment: I thought Diagram 6 of the paper gives quite a nice picture, or at any rate a picture, of how the 2-cell  of $RP^2$ is spread around the 2-cells of the product !